# FFmpeg scale+rotate+crop animation

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this code that scales and rotates a video input, over time:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=720x1280:rate=30 \
[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split=3[split1][split2][split3];\
[split1]trim=start=0:end=1[seg1];\
[split2]trim=start=1:end=1.01,loop=15:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale='iw+n*80':-1:eval=frame,rotate=0.1*PI*t:720:1280,crop=720:1280,[seg2];[seg2]split=2[seg2-1][seg2-2];\
[seg2-1]reverse,fifo,loop=25:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[seg3];\
[split3]setpts=PTS-1/TB,trim=start=0:end=2[seg4];\
[seg1][seg2-2][seg3][seg4]concat=n=4[comp] -map "[comp]" output.mp4
```

It looks something like this:
[image]

My challenge is:

- I would like **not** to use `reverse` but actual values in order to have full control over the reverse rotation/scale durations and timings.
  **Basically, can the rotate and scale filters print their values, per frame?**

Zoompan answers are valid. But please explain how to control the different values.

Comment: to reverse `...scale='iw+15*80-n*80':-1:eval=frame, rotate=0.1*PI*(0.5-t):720:1280...`

Answer (score 0):

I'll put it here so I don't forget:

```
#!/bin/bash
WID=1280
HEI=720
FPS=24000/1001

ffmpeg \
-ss 0.00 -to 1.00 -i input.mp4 \
-ss 1.00 -to 1.04 -i input.mp4 \
-ss 1.00 -to 2.80 -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "
[1:v]loop=12:1:0,
scale='iw+n*80':-1:eval=frame,
rotate=0.1*PI*t:${WID}:${HEI},
crop=${WID}:${HEI}[a];
anullsrc=cl='5.1(side)':r=48000:d=0.5[b];
[1:v]loop=12:1:0,
scale='iw+12*80-n*80':-1:eval=frame,
rotate=0.1*PI*(0.5-t):${WID}:${HEI},
crop=${WID}:${HEI},
setsar=1[c];
anullsrc=cl='5.1(side)':r=48000:d=0.5[d];
[0:v][0:a][a][b][c][d][2:v][2:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1
" -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -c:a aac -q:a 5 -y /tmp/output.mp4 -hide_banner

ffplay -loop 0 /tmp/output.mp4 -hide_banner
```